# How to Make Part of an Element Disappear When It's Behind Another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the borders to disappear only when they are behind the other elements. Similar to the screenshot. Does anyone know how to make the certain part of the border to disappear once it goes behind another element.

When `.border` goes behind `.mobile-toggle` and `.hero-details` I want that specific part of `.border` to disappear. So it looks cuts off, like it shows in the image.
Here's the page https://wordpress-324331-1192326.cloudwaysapps.com/ and below it's simplified code.
[image]

Here's a Codepen simplified example: https://codepen.io/elemusma/pen/RwPXMRJ?editors=1100

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">
  <span style="border-top:2px solid black;with:50px;height:50px;"></span>
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggle mobile-toggle" type="button" id="open-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</button>
<div class="home" id="home" style="background:url('https://wordpress-324331-1192326.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Welcome-Luxury-Compass.jpg');">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2054761/Luxury-Logo.png" width="250" class="logo"/>
  <div class="hero">
                <div class="hero-details text-center">
            <h4 class="bodoni subtitle">Positioning</h4>
            <h6>You to a <strong>Higher Level</strong></h6>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home{
  position:relative;
  height:500px;
}
.mobile-toggle{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:90px;
  z-index:9;
}
.mobile-toggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 36px;
    height: 7px;
    background: #232323;
    content: "";
    margin: 3px 0px;
}
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo{
  transform:translate(100%, -50%);
  position:absolute;
}
.border{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:90%;
  width:90%;
}
```

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] by posting the actual code?

Comment: @SuperStormer I added a minimal reproducible example. I apologize, I couldn't get my head around on how to reproduce it. But please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please explain what do you want exactly: what should be hidden ans when?

Comment: @djcaesar9114, I updated my question but basically, I want the specific parts of `.border` that crosses through the other elements like, `.logo`, `.hero-details` and `.mobile-toggle` to disappear.